# Combine AutoInclude with Filtered Include

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am looking for a solution to something like what was mentioned in:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21991#issuecomment-671595562

> Given we have NavigationBuilder, it would be better to put them on NavigationBuilder.
>
> ```cs
> modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Navigation(e => e.Courses).HasIncludeFilter(e => e.Where(course => course.Difficulty >10));
> ```
>
> @AndriySvyryd - Do we need a generic Navigation Builder now?

I noticed however, that `Navigation()` together with `AutoInclude()` does not seem to support filtered include. Is there any alternative way to achieve this in `EntityTypeBuilder`?

I was looking to use that with generics to get a translated entry or a fallback. I first tried:

```cs
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TTranslatable> builder) {
    builder.HasMany(p => p.Translations)
      .WithOne(c => c.Parent)
      .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId)
      .IsRequired()
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
  
    builder.Navigation(
       p => p.Translations.Where(t => t.Language == requestLanguage || t.IsDefaultLanguage == true)
         .OrderBy(t => t.IsDefaultLanguage)
         .Take(1)
       )
       .AutoInclude();

    base.Configure(builder);
  }
```

But, though it compiles, it throws an exception at runtime, complaining that the `Where`|`OrderBy`|`Take` clause should be removed: only a simple `p => p.Translations` should be referenced.

Is there any way to achieve something like this without having to repeat the **filtered include** in every individual query?

Comment: Well, no, hence the [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30883) the issue you mention refers to.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a feature request that can't be worked around.

Comment: Well, to be fair, that is not a feature request. The  original feature request was mentioned in the link I referenced at the beginning and was declined with a reasoning I was unable to understand. This is a question that I placed both in Github and Stackoverflow to check if there is a known **alternative** that may have escaped me.